# Font Awsome Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Im using bootstrap framework for my application, and want to use the font within the framework, but when i use the glypicon it changes my font to what seems like New times roman. I am using ASP MVC with Razor. I have tried to target this by changing the font within FA, but its seems to effect the icon itself and just show a square. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" Dashboard", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "fa fa-tachometer" })
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" Bookings", "Index", "Booking", null, new { @class = "fa fa-book" })
                </li>

                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" Jobs", "", "Jobs", null, new { @class = "fa fa-wrench" })
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" Manage Mechanics", "Mechanics", "Mechanic", null, new { @class = "fa fa-group" })
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="reports">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle fa fa-folder-open" data-toggle="dropdown">Reports</a>
                    <ul id="stats" class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Mechanic Ranking", "Rankings", "Report", null, new { @class = "fa fa-pie-chart" })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Mechanic Stats", "MechanicStats", "Report", null, new { @class = "fa fa-line-chart" })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Mechanic Jobs", "MechanicJobs", "Report", null, new { @class = "fa fa-area-chart" })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Category Stats", "JobCategoryStats", "Report", null, new { @class = "fa fa-bar-chart" })</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: what browser do you use? Have you add link to fonts in head section?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle with your html, css and js

Comment: I am using chrome. This is done within MVC, have no js, its all handled in the Bundle config